# Issue with recording Google Hangouts calls

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6, google-hangouts, google-voice, call-recording

I'm trying to record my Google Hangouts calls. The only app I found that claimed it can record non-dialer calls was Cube ACR. Problem is I'm getting a "Recording failed. Write to storage failure, unavailable audio source or unsupported audio format" error. How to fix this?

P.S. I'm using Samsung S6.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue for a little while now and tried everything, disabling even Knox software and Google Play and anything else that seems to be recording in the background, researched online found nothing.

The solution was actually my first instinct actually:

- Go into your android settings, scroll down and select `About Device`.
- Scroll down to the last item `RESET` but you DONT do a Factory data reset just the first option `Reset Settings (Reset all settings to their defaults)`. It wont delete your data but it should fix the issue.
- After doing the previous step, my phone restarted. Then when I went to use the native phone dialer software, an upgraded video dialer suddenly appeared (which I guess was half installed in the background).

I have Android 7.0. Not sure if its the same issue with others because there are scenarios from 2015 i was checking into but whatever the reason try `Reset Settings`.